# Geb - how to use hasNot function?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, geb

I want to find every navigator that has class "non-clicable" but does not have class "hide".
I write this

```
$(".non-clicable").hasNot(".hide")
```

but it's does not work (find every navigator that matches ".non-clicable" and hasNot is like ignored. I also tried to debug and found this:
[image]

Already I used

```
($(".non-clicable") - $(".non-clicable").filter(".hide"))
```

And it's works correctly but does not look to elegant.
Is there some bug or that I use the function in incorrect way?

Comment: How about `$(".non-clicable:not(.hide)")`  does that work ?

Comment: Yes that works. Thnaks.

Comment: FYI, `hasNot()` creates a new navigator by finding all elements in a navigator **that have descendants matching the selector** passed to it and `not()` creates a new navigator by removing all elements from a navigator **that match the selector** passed to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
$(".non-clicable", class: notContains(".hide"))
```

Or:

```
$(".non-clicable").not(".hide")
```

Also work:

```
$(".non-clicable",not : "hide")
```

Comment: First example does not work, but I changed it on 
$(".non-clicable",not : "hide")
and works fine.
Thanks.